# AFNetworkActivity bitcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, bitcode

I am using AFNetworking in the project which is using cocoapods to import

And the project required me to turn on the "BitCode"

So I switch the AFNetworking to 3.0 version

And AFNetworkActivityLogger also require to use 3.0.0 version
Therefore I add the below code into the Podfile

> pod 'AFNetworkActivityLogger', :git => 'https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworkActivityLogger.git', :branch => '3_0_0'

pod install is completed with no error found,

But the project is build failed with below error:

> (AFNetworkActivityConsoleLogger.o)' was built without full bitcode. All object files and libraries for bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build for architecture arm64

Can't find any related post, May i have some helps on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Refer this:- https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2986

> The 3.0.0 branch has Carthage Support that does enable bitcode, and to
>   my knowledge there is nothing specific a library maintainer needs to
>   do in order to support bitcode for Cocoapods.

Comment: Thanks! 
But I have already using the 3.0.0 branch with the above Podfile,
It still states that AFNetworkActivityConsoleLogger is not support bitcode

Comment: Your pod will not work , you have install it using Carthage!   Check this how to install it with https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#installation-with-carthage

Comment: I see, Thanks for your answer!
I think I require another huge processes to work with Carthage.

Comment: Hi Vizllx, when i am adding the AFNetworkActivityLogger by Carthage, i find the branch is not exist anymore, it display the error like https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/1167